# basic setup of appengine-rest-server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I download the appengine-rest-server (1.0.8) and try to use this module in my application but i get '404 error', when testing with:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/metadata
http://localhost:8080/rest/metadata/GPSLog
```

Has anybody a working example with python 2.7.2 ?

Following my code to initalize the module:

```
rest.Dispatcher.base_url = '/rest'
rest.Dispatcher.add_models({
  "GPSLog": models.GPSLog})
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([<Some other Routs> ,
                                  ('/rest/.*', rest.Dispatcher)], debug=True)
```

The log says it's loading my model. Any any idea on what the app.yaml should look like?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using python 2.7 your app.yaml handler entry would look something like:

```
application: yourapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /rest/.*
  script: your_module.application
```